# Flutter FutureBuilder throwing exception with Firebase Phone Auth "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-futurebuilder, dart-null-safety

**I am receiving following  exception when using a FutureBuilder to build itself using a future "firebaseAuthSvc.signinwithphoneno(widget.pin, widget.verificationID)" that return Firebase Authentication UserCredential.**

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ The following _CastError was
> thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state:
> _FutureBuilderState#a7b44): Null check operator used on a null value
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was FutureBuilder
> lib/screens/enterpinsubwidgetsecondscreen.dart:34 When the exception
> was thrown, this was the stack
> #0      UserInfo.uid package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/user_info.dart:52
> #1      UserInfo.toString package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/user_info.dart:57
> #2      StringBuffer.write (dart:core-patch/string_buffer_patch.dart:64:22)
> #3      StringBuffer.writeAll (dart:core-patch/string_buffer_patch.dart:102:7)
> #4      IterableBase.iterableToFullString (dart:collection/iterable.dart:267:14)

**My stateful widget using the future builder is as below.**

```
class _EnterPinSubWidgetSecondScreenState
    extends State<EnterPinSubWidgetSecondScreen> {
  FirebaseAuthSvc firebaseAuthSvc = new FirebaseAuthSvc();
  Future<UserCredential> _usercredential ;
  @override
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Pin:${widget.pin} VerificationID: ${widget.verificationID}");
    _usercredential =
       firebaseAuthSvc.signinwithphoneno(widget.pin, widget.verificationID);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Buildcontext of EnterPinSubWidgetSecondScreen");
    return FutureBuilder<UserCredential>(
      future: _usercredential,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(
            "in EnterPinSubWidgetSecondScreen builder ${snapshot.connectionState} data= ${snapshot.data}");
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print("Some error in snapshot ${snapshot.error}");
          return EnterPin();
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          
          return EnterPinSubWidgetThirdScreen();
        }

       
        return LoadingScr("Signining in...");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My future using firebase phone authentication signinwithcredential is defined as

```
Future<UserCredential> signinwithphoneno(
      String pin, String verificationID) async {
    String smsCode = pin;
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    // Create a PhoneAuthCredential with the code
    PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationID, smsCode: smsCode);
    // Sign the user in (or link) with the credential
     return auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).then((user) {
        print("User not null ${user.user.phoneNumber}");

       return user;
     
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      print("signingwithcredential returned error  $error");
      return null;
    });
  }
```

Comment: do you solve it ?